# How do the timings work for online_followers in insights on instagram graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

According to the documentation, the end_time is when the cutoff point for when the data starts:

> The end_time property indicates a data set's lookback cutoff date; data older than this value is not included in the data set's calculation.

When looking at online_followers in insights, the data looks like this:

```
{
          "value": {
            "0": 18634,
            "1": 18604,
            "2": 19849,
            "3": 21491,
            "4": 23519,
            "5": 25000,
            "6": 24772,
            "7": 25081,
            "8": 25408,
            "9": 25883,
            "10": 26216,
            "11": 26591,
            "12": 27182,
            "13": 27398,
            "14": 25384,
            "15": 19336,
            "16": 13968,
            "17": 11596,
            "18": 10770,
            "19": 10156,
            "20": 9967,
            "21": 11243,
            "22": 14837,
            "23": 18040
},
"end_time": "2021-07-01T07:00:00+0000"
```

Do the numbers refer to the hour of the day? Or do they refer to the number of hours that have passed since 07:00:00? If the latter, would this data be for 2021-07-21 and 2021-07-22?

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights),

> "Metrics that support lifetime periods will have results returned in
> an array of 24 hour periods, with periods ending on UTC−07:00"

UTC-07:00 corresponds to [US Pacific Time](https://time.is/PT) (PDT) 0 AM (midnight/start of a new day)

so, for anyone in that time zone, the number of hours passing since that UTC Timestamp IS EQUAL to the hour of the day. In your example, that data is for every hour of the day 2021-07-01 in PDT.

Comment: Thank you for clear description!
But I'm confused because I got `"end_time": "2024-01-09T08:00:00+0000"` rather than `07:00:00+0000`. Is this related to summer-time v.s. winter-time? It looks suspicious as the documentation suggests "UTC−07:00" clearly...